# Meaning of "very occasional"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In my preparation for exam, I found "very occasional" in context of giving full points for answers that are showing no or little errors.

Does "very occasional" mean:  very seldom, almost perfect or no errors ?

I think so, but I want you to confirm my understanding, please.

Comment: **Very occasional** in this context means what the author intended it to mean. You could certainly take it to mean *very seldom* although this could refer to one answer in twenty, in a hundred or in a thousand.

Answer (score 1):

Very occasional doesn't mean almost perfect on its own. You need to say, for example, *an essay with very occasional errors*. Or there might be a table with a heading **grammar mistakes** and rows with *none*, *very occasional*, *frequent*  and so on.

It is a matter of judgement exactly how many "very occasional" might be. That is a judgement made by the teacher.

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned, the stated phrase "very occasional" appears in the line for 10 Points out of 10. So it obviously refers to the maximum possible / available number of points. (LCCI B2 EXAM Grammar-Assessment). So yes, it´s within a table.